# How can I emulate Modules / Installers / Registries with Simple Injector

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, ioc-container, simple-injector

Autofac has modules, Windsor has Installers and StructureMap Registries ... with Simple Injector how can I pack configuration logic into reusable classes?

I have tried:

```
public interface IModule { }

public class FooModule : IModule
{
    public FooModule(SimpleInjector.Container container)
    {
        container.RegisterSingleton<IBar, Bar>();
        container.RegisterSingleton<IFoo, Foo>();
    }
}
```

And I use it in the Composition Root:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var container = new SimpleInjector.Container();
    container.RegisterCollection<IModule>(new FooModule(container));
    ...
}
```

However, `FooModule` depends on container and maybe in not a good practice...
see http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/BestPractices:

> If components have a dependency on the container, look at how they're using the 
>   container to retrieve services, and add those services to the component's (dependency 
>   injected) constructor arguments instead.

Comment: Note that -even with Autofac- your `FooModule` will depend on the container (or with Autofac, the `ContainerBuilder, since Autofac splits the container in two types). Take a look at [this Autofac documentation](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/StructuringWithModules) and you'll clearly see that modules take this dependency. For a module, you simply need the container, but that doesn't matter since a module will be part of your composition root.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A 'module' feature is deliberately left out of the Simple Injector core library, but there is a [SimpleInjector.Packaging NuGet package](https://nuget.org/packages/SimpleInjector.Packaging) that allows you to do this. 'Package' is the term Simple Injector uses. This library however, is nothing more than one `IPackage` interface and two extension methods. You can achieve the same by writing code like this:

A package:

```cs
public static class BootstrapperPackage
{
    public static void RegisterServices(Container container)
    {
        container.Register<IBar, Bar>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
        container.Register<IFoo, Foo>(Lifestyle.Singleton);            
    }
}
```

In your composition root:

```cs
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var container = new SimpleInjector.Container();

    BootstrapperPackage.RegisterServices(container);

    ...
}
```

The difference with the [SimpleInjector.Packaging NuGet package](https://nuget.org/packages/SimpleInjector.Packaging) is that this package defines an interface for you, and allows you to dynamically load multiple packages in one single line:

```
public class BusinessLayerPackage : IPackage
{
    public void RegisterServices(Container container)
    {
        container.Register<IBar, Bar>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
        container.Register<IFoo, Foo>(Lifestyle.Singleton);            
    }
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var container = new SimpleInjector.Container();

    container.RegisterPackages(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());
}
```

However, if you don't really need dynamic loading, using static methods (as shown above) is preferred, because it has the following advantages:

- Makes loading modules very explicit and discoverable.
- Makes it easy to select which modules to load and which not.
- Makes it easy to pass along extra values to the `RegisterServices` methods, such as configuration values that such module requires. This prevents the module from taking a hard dependency on the configuration system.

For more information, please read [this](https://simpleinjector.org/howto#package-registrations).

Comment: Thanks Steven, ...but is it correct to pass container to other classes?

Comment: No it isn't, but a module is not part of the application code, but part of the [composition root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot.aspx), which makes it an infrastructure component. It is okay to use the container inside your infrastructure components. Mark Seemann describes this clearly [here](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/08/25/ServiceLocatorRolesVsMechanics.aspx).

Comment: Why was this feature left out of the core library?

Comment: @Sam: It's left out of the core library to keep the core library's API small. Packaging is a feature that's not needed very often and as I show in the code example, in most scenarios you can easily achieve the same without the SimpleInjector.Packaging NuGet package.

Comment: I find this feature really valuable when you have a solution with many projects and each project exposes both interfaces (for some services) and implementations (for other services). One (or even more) package(s) per-project, each up to define local registrations: clean. The possibility to load packages through assembly scanning provides very loose coupling between composition-root and other projects.

Comment: @Marcello: Unless your application uses a plugin model, where assemblies are dropped in a 'plugin' directory and loaded dynamically, the application's entry point will _always_ have a [dependency on _all_ other assemblies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9501604/) in the system. It is the most _volatile_ part in the system and dynamically loading parts of your Composition Root dynamically doesn't change that. Package scanning is therefore discouraged for any assembly that is known at compile-time.

Comment: Thanks @Steven. My apps have not plugins. I am very interested in the best practice for a good composition root (mark seeman's book is only one of my readings) since, though I love DI, this aspect is still one of my 'hard steps'.I shared my current best practice here: https://github.com/supix/Diploy What I really like about this approach (see pros section) is to declare implementations as private classes. I would be very glad to learn a better practice.

Comment: @Marcello: the [second edition](https://manning.com/seemann2) will contain [more detailed information](https://livebook.manning.com/#!/book/dependency-injection-in-dot-net-second-edition/chapter-4/v-6/99) about this.